# C++ algorithms that create their output-storage instead of being applied to existing storage?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, standard-library, boost-range

The [C++ std algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) define a number of algorithms that take an input and an output sequence, and create the elements of the output sequence from the elements of the input sequence. (Best example being [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/).)

The std algorithms obviously take `iterators`, so there's no question that the container for the `OutputIterator` has to exist prior to the algorithm being invoked.

That is:

```
std::vector<int> v1; // e.g. v1 := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

std::vector<int> squared;
squared.reserve(v1.size()); // not strictly necessary
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(squared), 
               [](int x) { return x*x; } ); // λ for convenience, needn't be C++11
```

And this *is fine as far as the std library goes*. When I find iterators too cumbersome, I often look to [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) to simplify things.

In this case however, it seems that the [mutating algorithms in Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating.html) *also* use `OutputIterators`.

So I'm currently **wondering whether there's any convenient library out there**, that allows me to write:

```
std::vector<int> const squared = convenient::transform(v1, [](int x) { return x*x; });
```

-- and if there is none, **whether there is a reason that there is none**?

Edit: *example implementation* (not sure if this would work in all cases, and whether this is the most ideal one):

```
template<typename C, typename F>
C transform(C const& input, F fun) {
   C result;
   std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(result), fun);
   return result;
}
```

(Note: I think `convenient::transform` will have the same performance characteristics than the handwritten one, as the returned vector won't be copied due to (N)RVO. Anyway, I think performance is secondary for this question.)

---

Edit/Note: Of the answers(comments, really) given so far, [David gives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203278/c-algorithms-that-create-their-output-storage-instead-of-being-applied-to-exist/7204760#7204760) a very nice basic generic example.

And [Luc mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203278/c-algorithms-that-create-their-output-storage-instead-of-being-applied-to-exist/7204176#7204176) a possible problem with `std::back_inserter` wrt. genericity.

Both just go to show why I'm hesitating to whip this up myself and why a "proper" (properly tested) library would be preferable to coding this myself.

My question phrased in bold above, namely *is there one, or is there a reason there is none* remains largely unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Boost.Range.Adaptors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors.html) can be kind of seen as container-returning algorithms. Why not use them?

The only thing that needs to be done is to define a new range adaptor `create<T>` that can be piped into the adapted ranges and produces the desired result container:

```
template<class T> struct converted{}; // dummy tag class

template<class FwdRange, class T>
T operator|(FwdRange const& r, converted<T>){
  return T(r.begin(), r.end());
}
```

Yep, that's it. No need for anything else. Just pipe that at the end of your adaptor list.

[Here *could* be a live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/5s3TX) Alas, it isn't, because Ideone doesn't provide Boost in C++0x mode.. meh. In any case, here's `main` and the output:

```
int main(){
  using namespace boost::adaptors;
  auto range = boost::irange(1, 10);
  std::vector<int> v1(range.begin(), range.end());

  auto squared = v1 | transformed([](int i){ return i * i; });
  boost::for_each(squared, [](int i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
  std::cout << "\n========================\n";
  auto modded = squared | reversed
                        | filtered([](int i){ return (i % 2) == 0; })
                        | converted<std::vector<int>>(); // gimme back my vec!
  modded.push_back(1);
  boost::for_each(modded, [](int i){ std::cout << i << " "; });
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
========================
64 36 16 4 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not meant as an answer to the question itself, it's a complement to the other answers -- but it wouldn't fit in the comments.

> well - what if you wanted list or deque or some other sequence type container - it's pretty limiting.

```
namespace detail {

template<typename Iter, typename Functor>
struct transform {
    Iter first, last;
    Functor functor;

    template<typename Container> // SFINAE is also available here
    operator Container()
    {
        Container c;
        std::transform(first, last, std::back_inserter(c), std::forward<Functor>(functor));
        return c;
    }
};

} // detail

template<typename Iter, typename Functor>
detail::transform<Iter, typename std::decay<Functor>::type>
transform(Iter first, Iter last, Functor&& functor)
{ return { first, last, std::forward<Functor>(functor) }; }
```

While this would work with a handful of containers, it's still not terribly generic since it requires that the container be 'compatible' with `std::back_inserter(c)` (BackInsertable?). Possibly you could use SFINAE to instead use `std::inserter` with `c.begin()` if `c.push_back()` is not available (left as an exercise to the reader).

All of this also assume that the container is DefaultConstructible -- consider containers that make use of scoped allocators. Presumably *that* loss of genericity is a feature, as we're only trying to cover the 'simplest' uses.

And this is in fact while I would not use such a library: I don't mind creating the container just outside next to the algorithm to **separate the concerns**. (I suppose this can be considered my answer to the question.)

Comment: Luc - thanks for your last paragraph. Why would you *want to* separate the concerns in this case? I *want to* create a transformed copy of my container -- why should I use 2(3) lines for that instead of 1. (And additionally loose the possibility to declare the result `const`.)

Comment: @Martin Terribly sorry, my example addresses more or less your example implementation rather than your intent. I'm also running out of time right now for this discussion, but wouldn't `std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), c.begin(), functor)` be the right thing to do?

Comment: I just noticed you said *copy*. Then I still want separation of concerns, e.g. the allocation schemes of the logical copy and the original are orthogonal this way. In this spirit you can use my previous suggestion as: `auto copy = c; std::transform(copy.begin(), copy.end(), copy.begin());`. Easy to understand (the algorithm is separate from the allocation/container creation); easy to maintain (change `copy` to `std::vector<int, some_scoped_allocator> copy(` *pass stuff to the allocator and copy from c* `);` ).

Comment: Luc - Yes, you could do this via copy. But the version with the copy is rather inefficient: It passed twice over the input; it copies the original values unmodified and then modifies them. I rather would use the version with the back_inserter: Same amount of lines (2) and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the point of such an algorithm is to be *generic*, i.e. mostly container agnostic. What you are proposing is that the `transform` function be very specific, and return a `std::vector`, well - what if you wanted `list` or `deque` or some other sequence type container - it's pretty limiting.

Why not wrap if you find it so annoying? Create your own little utilities header which does this - after all, it's pretty trivial...

Comment: The `transform` function the OP proposes may not return a `std::vector` since the return type could be a template parameter.

Comment: @Antonio Perez, it would have to be deduced from the input type, hence would have to be the same(?) I don't see a specific template parameter in the call to specify a *different* return type?

Comment: right, I just pointed out that it doesn´t have to be a specific version returning a `std:vector`, could work on any sequence as long as the return type is the same as the input type (as you noted)

Comment: I added a templated example to prevent confusion.

Comment: It is not limited to `vector` but to whatever the container passed in is. Also that limitation can be removed by adding an argument to the template: `template <typename OutC, typename C, typename F>`, to simplify calls when the type of the container does not need to change you can provide another template: `template <typename C, typename F> transform( C const & c, F f ) { return transform<C,C,F>(c,f); }` Calling code could be `std::vector<int> v2 = transform( v1, [](int i) { return 2*i; } );` and `std::deque<int> q = transform<std::deque<int> >( v1, [](int i){ return 2*i; } );`

Comment: @David: Are your sure this can be implemented to work with all _containers_?

Comment: @Nim: "Why not wrap if you find it so annoying? ..." JBC! Yeah. Why not just re-implement the whole algorithm header, after all *it's pretty trivial*. **Because I do not want to reinvent the wheel**. (As I would, for example, do in *other* related circumstances, if I were to wrap iterators myself instead of using Boost.Range.)

Comment: @Martin, why do you have to re-implement the whole algorithm header? you're only concerned about a subset of the algorithms which take an output iterator, wrap them as David has done above, and you'll still maintain their generic*ness*. It's an hour's work at most...

Comment: Nim - You see, when I do something that I feel is something someone else may have done before, I try to double check. I *don't* write algorithms myself because they're in the std header. I *try to avoid* writing wrappers myself, if there's a chance that *well-tested* ones already exist.

Comment: @Martin, clearly that is the correct approach, and the point which I am trying to make is that, a library writer typically tries to provide something which can be used generically, you need something specific, the two won't come together - so you have to RYO. And in this case, it's a trivial task as only *you* know the specificity of what is required.

Comment: @phresnel: I have provided a complete implementation of that as a non-answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203278/c-algorithms-that-create-their-output-storage-instead-of-being-applied-to-exist/7204760#7204760), so I guess I am safe in assuming that it can be done.

Comment: Nim - as for the genericity (which you doubt), see [David's non-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203278/c-algorithms-that-create-their-output-storage-instead-of-being-applied-to-exist/7204760#7204760).

Answer (score 1):

There is no one and correct way of enabling

```
std::vector<int> const squared = 
             convenient::transform(v1, [](int x) { return x*x; });
```

without a potential performance cost. You either need an explicit

```
std::vector<int> const squared = 
             convenient::transform<std::vector> (v1, [](int x) { return x*x; });
```

Note the explicit mentioning of the container type: Iterators don't tell anything about the container they belong to. This becomes obvious if you remind that a container's iterator is allowed by the standard to be an ordinary pointer.

Letting the algorithm take a container instead of iterators is not a solution, either. That way, the algorithm can't know how to correctly get the first and last element. For example, a `long int`-array does not have methods for `begin()`, `end()` and `length()`, not all containers have random access iterators, not `operator[]` defined. So there is no truly generic way to take containers.

Another possibility that allows for container-agnostic, container-returning algorithms would be some kind of generic factory (see live at http://ideone.com/7d4E2):

```
// (not production code; is even lacking allocator-types)
//-- Generic factory. -------------------------------------------
#include <list>
template <typename ElemT, typename CacheT=std::list<ElemT> >
struct ContCreator {

    CacheT cache; // <-- Temporary storage.

    // Conversion to target container type.
    template <typename ContT>
    operator ContT () const {
        // can't even move ...
        return ContT (cache.begin(), cache.end());
    }
};
```

Not so much magic there apart from the templated cast operator. You then return that thing from your algorithm:

```
//-- A generic algorithm, like std::transform :) ----------------
ContCreator<int> some_ints () {
    ContCreator<int> cc;
    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i) {
        cc.cache.push_back (i*4);
    }
    return cc;
}
```

And finally use it like this to write magic code:

```
//-- Example. ---------------------------------------------------
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Iter;
    std::vector<int> vec = some_ints();
    for (Iter it=vec.begin(), end=vec.end(); it!=end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

As you see, in `operator T` there's a range copy.

A move might be possible by means of template specialization in case the target and source containers are of the same type.

Edit: As David points out, you can of course do the real work inside the conversion operator, which will come at probably no extra cost (with some more work it can be done more convenient; this is just for demonstration):

```
#include <list>
template <typename ElemT, typename Iterator>
struct Impl {
    Impl(Iterator it, Iterator end) : it(it), end(end) {}

    Iterator it, end;

    // "Conversion" + Work.
    template <typename ContT>
    operator ContT () {
        ContT ret;
        for ( ; it != end; ++it) {
            ret.push_back (*it * 4);
        }
        return ret;    
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
Impl<int,Iterator> foo (Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    return Impl<int,Iterator>(begin, end);
}

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Iter;

    const int ints [] = {1,2,4,8};
    std::vector<int> vec = foo (ints, ints + sizeof(ints) / sizeof(int));

    for (Iter it=vec.begin(), end=vec.end(); it!=end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

The one requirement is that the target has a `push_back` method. Using `std::distance` to reserve a size may lead to sub-optimal performance if the target-container-iterator is not a random-access one.

Comment: The container type can trivially be implicitly deduced from the first argument, why would you need to explicitly specify it?
/ I fail to see how the ContCreator example you gives answers the question.

Comment: @Martin, you could want to return a different kind of container to the input one. Of course, it is your question, so you know what behaviour you want :-)

Comment: @Martin: Iterators don't tell anything about the container they belong to. This becomes obvious if you remind that a container's iterator is allowed by the standard to be an ordinary pointer.

Comment: I don't follow the reasoning... what would be the performance cost? Why would passing the type of the container affect performance? (or are they unrelated?) How does the `ContCreator` tackle the problem? (i.e. `ContCreator` does have a performance impact). While returning a proxy object that will do the lazy evaluation may be a good idea (i.e. can hide the type of the receiver) the implementation should be lazy to avoid the extra copies, and that is trivially done, BTW, just store the two iterators and perform the `transform` on the conversion operator

Comment: @Martin: I updated my answer as for your container-taking algorithm.

Comment: @David: You are so right and this seems too obvious :) I updated my answer.

Comment: Quoting Alexandrescu about this form of lazy [evaluation](http://drdobbs.com/184403774): `;transform( v, functor );` *doesn't really do anything, and if you're the pensive type, such code might make you cogitate on the concept of a tree falling in the forest* -- if no-one is going to hear the tree, just avoid the hassle of having it fall.

Answer (score 1):

Again, a no-answer, but rather a follow up from the comments to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203278/c-algorithms-that-create-their-output-storage-instead-of-being-applied-to-exist/7203335#7203335)

**On the genericity of the returned type in the questions code**

The code as it stands does not allow the conversion of the return type, but that can be easily solvable by providing two templates:

```
template <typename R, typename C, typename F>
R transform( C const & c, F f ) {_
    R res;
    std::transform( c.begin(), c.end(), std::back_inserter(res), f );
    return res;
}
template <typename C, typename F>
C transform( C const & c, F f ) {
    return transform<C,C,F>(c,f);
}
std::vector<int> src;
std::vector<int> v = transform( src, functor );
std::deque<int>  d = transform<std::deque<int> >( src, functor );
```